# Receiving a publish error using project reference

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Visual Studio 2017 [ / 2019 ] ASP.NET Core web app project where I have enabled docker build output and publish target support.

The project makes use of a nuget package which has some issues that I'm trying to debug and fix by swapping out the nuget package reference and instead referencing fork of the project sources used to create the nuget package.

In the `.csproj` file excerpt below you can see where I commented out nuget package reference and am instead using a project reference to fork of project that produces dll distributed by that nuget package.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!--<PackageReference Include="SomeNugetPackage" Version="1.0.0" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\someNugetPackage.fork\src\SomeNugetPackage\SomeNugetPackage.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

All is good when I do an f5 debug of project with this setup, it builds and gets hosted by docker asp.net core container instance w/o any issues. The problem arises when I attempt to publish [ to the default docker targets which looks to be my personal docker hub registry and from there into azure container instance ].

The publish processing generates a dialog stating

> Publish failed | Publish has encountered an error. | Build failed. Check the Output window for more details. | A diagnostic log has been written to the following location: "%temp%\tmp5712.tmp" | OK

where the tmp file doesn't appear to have anything additional details of relevance. The project's Dockerfile can be found [here](https://mysawestus.blob.core.windows.net/public/Dockerfile) and the tmp5712.tmp file [here](https://mysawestus.blob.core.windows.net/public/tmp5712.tmp) .

The build output window does appear to have the telling detail which is the following.

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.502/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1879,5): Warning : The referenced project '../../someNugetPackage.fork/src/SomeNugetPackage/SomeNugetPackage.csproj' does not exist. [/src/AzWebApp1/AzWebApp1.csproj]
>   Startup.cs(9,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name '' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/src/AzWebApp1/AzWebApp1.csproj]

Is there some ASP.NET Core web app project Dockerfile setting one needs to make to handle pulling in a project reference's dll output for the publish build process which works w/o any special settings necessary in the f5 localhost debug build/rebuild cases?

Comment: It would be wise to provide your Dockerfile, and also the relevant parts of the contents of `%temp%\tmp5712.tmp`.

Comment: @John updated question to include links to Dockerfile and publish diagnostics tmp file as requested.